# Couple-Mode Theory: Coupling Coefficients of Two Resonators

Tags: optics, coupled-oscillators, photonics

I'm currently reading H. Haus book on "Wave and Fields in Optoeletronics". On the chapter of Coupling of Two Resonators Mode, the rate equations for the fields are introduced:

$$ \frac{da_1}{dt}=j\omega_1a_1 + k_{12}a_2$$
$$ \frac{da_2}{dt}=j\omega_2a_2 + k_{21}a_1$$

To find a relation between $k_{12}$ and $k_{21}$ he uses the fact that the total energy must be constant: $\frac{d}{dt}\left[|a_1|^2 + |a_2|^2\right] = 0$, which implies that:

$$a_1^*k_{12}a_2 + a_1k_{12}^*a_2^* + a_2^*k_{21}a_1 + a_2k_{21}^*a_1^*=0$$

Here is where my problem stars, he goes on and says: "Because the inicial amplitudes and phases of $a_1$ and $a_2$ can be set arbitrarily, the coupling coefficients must be related by:

$$k_{12} + k_{21}^* = 0"$$

How he got that? I really would appreciate some help.

Comment: hint: write your equation as $\Re [a_1^* (k_{12} +k_{21}^*)a_2]=0$

Comment: @hyportnex Thanks!